# How to hide Show section with menu click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a menu :

```
<ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#schedule" data-toggle="tab">schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="#speakers" data-toggle="tab">speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
            <li class="featured"><a href="register.html"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></i>Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to show/hide the corresponding sections :

```
<section id="about" class="section dark">
```

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want a menu click to show hide a sections?

Comment: I know it's not tagged but in Jquery all you need to say is `$(".section").toggle()`. In native JavaScript you have a function check the visibility of the element, and if it's hidden then show it, if it's shown then hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a structure like

```
<ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about" id="nav_about">About</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#schedule" data-toggle="tab">schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="#speakers" data-toggle="tab">speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
            <li class="featured"><a href="register.html"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></i>Register</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="sec-about" class="section dark"><h2>About</h2></section>
```

you could toggle the section like

```
document.getElementById('nav_about').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var secAbout = document.getElementById('sec-about');
    if( getComputedStyle(secAbout,null).display=='none') secAbout.style.display='block';
    else secAbout.style.display='none';
}, false);
```

Compare [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xa13kaj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `toggle()` method to do this in simple way.
Refer http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle